# unbounded derivation of von Neumann algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

(This post is cross post on https://mathoverflow.net/questions/405965/densely-defined-derivations-in-von-neumann-algebrain-norm-topology)

We know that all derivation on von Neumann algebra are inner. How about unbounded derivation? If we restrict the domain of the derivation is dense, do we have any unbounded derivation on abelian von Neumann algebra? I am mostly interested in the case of $l^{\infty}(\mathbb{N})$ and $L^{\infty}([0,1],\mu)$.

(Here, "unbounded derivation" means that the domain of derivation is at least dense in the algebra, which have nothing to do with the norm)

Comment: Do you want the domain to be dense in the weak$^\ast$ topology or in the norm topology?

Comment: I am interested in both cases. My gut feeling is there are no derivations in norm topology.

Comment: Can you take the Von Neumann algebra to be the $L^{\infty}$ functions on the circle, the dense sub-algebra be maybe the set of all finite fourier series and the derivative just normal derivative?